# SWT button position after resizing

Tags: java, swt

I'm working with SWT. I created a button, and it supposed to change its text after being pressed.
The second text is wider than the first one, and the button does not being re-sized appropriately.
so I used button.pack(), and setSize() functions. The real issue is actually with its  alignment in the shell after this size changing. 
it's being expanded to the right instead to the left. 
I guess it's actually the normal behavior,  but I'm not sure where to change it. 
I tried to change things by creating a gridData but it only did worse.

The button parent is tabFolder, and the last consists of a gridlayout with two uneven columns, the spesific button is on the second column.
I tried to change things with the margins and few others, but without success.

currently all the configurations are default.

This is my button:

### [image: This is my button:]

This is how I would like it to behave:

### [image: This is the desired behavior:]

any help would be highly appreciated.
many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would need some code to be sure, but it looks like you need to call `tabFolder.layout(true)` after changing the button text to compute the new position of your button